# Hibernate: updating entity by the values from the DTO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I think it's quite common pattern when we have an entity with some collections and want to update it by the front end.

```
class Parent {
    long id;
    List<Child> childs;
}

class Child {
    long id;
    String property;
}

class ParentDTO {
    long id;
    List<ChildDTO> childs;
}

class ChildDTO {
    long id;
    String property;
}
```

Now I have a method like

```
public void createOrUpdate(ParentDTO parentDTO) {
    Parent parent;
    if (parentDTO.id == 0L) {
        parent = new Parent();
        parent.childs = ChildDTO.convertToEntities(parentDTO.childs);
    } else {
        parent = em.find(Parent.class, parentDTO.id);
        syncParent(parent, parentDTO);
    }

    em.saveOrUpdate(parent);
}

public static void syncParent(Parent parent, ParentDTO parentDTO) {
    // this will cause issues due to setting session attached 
    // parent.childs collection to a new one
    // parent.childs = ChildDTO.convertToEntities(parentDTO.childs);

   // the better way is 
   parent.childs.clear();
   parent.childs.addAll(ChildDTO.convertToEntities(parentDTO.childs);)

   // however let's look at convert method
}

public static List<Child> convertToEntities(List<ChildDTO> childDTOs) {
    //let's skip iteration
    Child child = new Child();
    child.id = childDTO.id;
    child.property = childDTO.property;
    // return childs
}
```

The issue here is that if I set an id to the Child from the ChildDTO trying to update the existing Child - hibernate will throw a "detached entity passed to persist" exception.

I know two ways of fixing that:

1. Don't set an id, thus the childs will get the new ids every time they are persisted
2. Traverse the collection of existing childs and find corresponding childDTOs (with the same id), then copy the values

The second way is cumbersome if you have even deeper hierarchy. Is there anyway to do things right, i.e. when id is set to the Child hibernate will figure out that it should actually reload the Child() with that id from em and update it with the new fields.

What's the right way of solving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a perfect use case for [EntityManager::merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge-T-):

> Merge the state of the given entity into the current persistence
>   context.